# Django - Inline (has no ForeignKey to)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement `InlineModels` but I'm getting error message. Will you please help me? Thank you .

## myproject.api.models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from myproject.song.models import Album, Song, Artist

class UserLibrary(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

## myproject.api.admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.song.models import Song, Album, Artist, Music
from myproject.api.models import UserLibrary

class SongInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Song
class UserLibraryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['user']
    inlines = [
        SongInline,
        ]
admin.site.register(UserLibrary, UserLibraryAdmin)
```

Here is my traceback:

```
 Exception at /admin/api/userlibrary/add/
<class 'myproject.song.models.Song'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'api.models.UserLibrary'>
```

Comment: Does your `Song` class have a field like `library = models.ForeignKey(UserLibrary)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've built the wrong relationship--your `Song` model should have a foreign key relationship to the `UserLibrary` model, not the other way around. Other than that, everything seems to be correct.

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Shouldn't it be able to go both ways?