# Django - <class> has no ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm setting up Django admins with:

**model.py**

```
class Types(models.Model):
    types = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type

class File(models.Model):
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Types)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file_name

class Set(models.Model):
    set_name = models.CharField(default='New Set', max_length=60)
    data = models.DateTimeField('Date of creation')
    file = models.ForeignKey(File)
    size = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return ("%s - %s" % (self.set_name, str(self.data)))

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["data"]
```

And at **admin.py**

```
class FileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = File
    extra = 2

class SetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,      {'fields':['set_name']}),
        (None,      {'fields':['data']}),
        (None,      {'fields':['size']}),
    ]
    inlines = [FileInline]

admin.site.register(Set, SetAdmin)
```

With this I'm getting the following error:

> (admin.E202) 'Disk.File' has no ForeignKey to 'Disk.Set'

According to documentation in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey it was supposed to work.

I did some tests with: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-a-model-with-two-or-more-foreign-keys-to-the-same-parent-model but without sucess. Inverting the classes, making File with ForeignKey from Set also didn't work.

From Django tutorial I've managed to get the relationship working, but i'm falling at replicate it.

I've checked the suggestions on the following posts:
[Inline in Django admin: has no ForeignKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899523/inline-in-django-admin-has-no-foreignkey) and
[Django - Inline (has no ForeignKey to)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526159/django-inline-has-no-foreignkey-to) but i couldn't figure out what is wrong.

I'm using Python 2.7.6, Django 1.8.4, MySQL 5.6 and Ubuntu 14.04.

I would really appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: What error do you get when you invert the FK?

Comment: Disk.File does not have fk to Disk.set, is the other way around it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trimming back your code the problem is this - in your models you are saying :

> A  `Set` has one `File`, and a `File` has many `Set`s

But your admin file says:

> A `Set` can have many `File`s

These are two contradictory statements. You need to make them match, **either**:

Fix your models:

```
class File(models.Model):
    # Add the below line
    file = models.ForeignKey(Set) 

class Set(models.Model):
    # Delete this line
    # file = models.ForeignKey(File)
```

Or fix your admin - which is a complete rewrite, and the above seems what you want anyway.